# Saving a form part way through mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm pretty new to MongoDB and best practices. I'm using Node full stack JS.

I created a form which spans multiple screens. This saves to a mongoose.model Schema and creates a document when the user submits the form.

I've been given the requirement to allow the user to save the form when part way through. The problem with trying to save to the existing Schema is I get a duplicate id reference error as I'm saving multiple fields as null which already exist in the Collection. Plus I'm thinking this is a waste of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very simple it just took me some circular thinking to get to it. I check to see if properties are undefined before setting them. If they are undefined they are an empty value rather than null i.e. {} for an Object. Mongoose is ok with that, it just doesn't like null values (makes sense).